# query for returning the changes in the last month

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a DB that stores details of our contract clients - we need to check every month if they have moved base. So trying to run a query that will return any that have changed homebase in the last month.

Using mySQL phpmyadmin localhost via Unix socket, for is set as the month i.e. '07-2013' as VARCHAR.

```
SELECT crewcode, firstname, surname, homebase,'for' AS 'Date'
FROM  `hours` 
WHERE homebase ...
```

not sure what I need here? need to see if homebase has changed in the last month from 06-2013 to 07-2013

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would say this is a design issue with your database, it sound like homebase is a date and should rather be saved as a DateTime, but it is what it is, so I suggest that you convert/cast the homebase to a proper DateTime so that you can do proper date comparisons.

Comment: Sorry homebase is a country i.e NYO

Comment: Do you have a DateTime field in the database that is updated when the homebase field is changed?

Comment: for is the date range but is set as VARCHAR.

Comment: Generally I prefer to include an 'Update' field in my database design that is updated to the latest date and time when any of the rows is modified. You will have to do something similar to keep track of when the homebase was last modified, with the exception that the field is only updated to the latest date and time when the homebase changed. Another solution is to keep a change history within another database table. Without keeping a history of some sort you will not be able to track if the homebase changed.

Comment: If for is an acceptable field to use then cast/convert the field from VARCHAR to DATETIME and do the comparison as explained by Thorsten Kettner below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for anyone interested:

```
 SELECT A.employee_ID as crewcode,
        A.emp_firstname, 
        emp_lastname, 
        B.base, 
        B.base_for AS  'Date'
   FROM `hs_hr_employee` as A,
        `employee_base_table` as B 
  where B.base_for=(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE( CURDATE( ) , '%Y-%m-%d' ),'%m-%Y')) 
    AND A.emp_number=B.emp_number 
  group by A.employee_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

To look for changes in the last 30 days:

```
WHERE mydate > curdate() - interval 30 day
```

To look for changes in the last calendar month:

```
WHERE year(mydate) = year(curdate()) and month(mydate) = month(curdate()) - 1
```

Comment: for is not set as date it's VARCHAR. I need to check if the country homebase has changed from '06-2013'to '07-2013'

Answer (score 0):

You can try joining the same query and add in the ON condition `table1.homebase!=table2.homebase`

if this query returns you the data for a particular date

```
SELECT crewcode, firstname, surname, homebase,'for' AS 'Date'
FROM  `hours` 
WHERE homebase ...
```

Then you can try

```
SELECT a1.crewcode
FROM
(

SELECT crewcode, firstname, surname, homebase,'for' AS 'Date'
FROM  `hours` 
WHERE homebase ... //data for first month )a1

INNER JOIN
(

SELECT crewcode, firstname, surname, homebase,'for' AS 'Date'
FROM  `hours` 
WHERE homebase ... //data for second month
 )a2
ON a1.crewcode=a2.crewcode AND a1.homebase!=a2.homebase
```